# Поиск в массиве по компоненту значения (сложный тип)

Tags: c++, c++11, поиск, c++14, find

На ночь глядя голова не варит уже. Подскажите как решить следующую проблему самым эффективным (быстрым) способом на C++11, C++14, в общем не на старье :)

Итак:

```
typedef std::pair<int, int> data_pr;
typedef std::vector<data_pr> data_t;
```

как правильно получить итератор на значение:

```
data_t mydata;

data_t::iterator it = std::find(mydata.begin(), mydata.end(), value);
```

И необходимо, чтобы поиск выполнялся по функции у которой входные параметры - элемент вектора `data_t`, т.е. `data_pr` и `value`

И дальше проверить просто:

```
if (element.first == value)
```

Или быстрее всего будет самому в лоб делать перебор?

Comment: Вектор предварительно отсортирован?

Comment: Если нет, то `std::find_if` с лямбдой в качестве третьего параметра.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Если вектор не отсортирован, то вряд ли получится найти нужный элемент быстрее, чем за O(n) с помощью линейного поиска.

Поскольку проверку выполняет некий алгоритм, а не обычное сравнение, то стоит использовать `std::find_if`:

---

**Лямбда**

```
data_t mydata;
int value = 0;

data_t::iterator it = 
    std::find_if(
        mydata.begin(),
        mydata.end(),
        [value](const data_pr& elem) { return elem.first == value; }
    );
```

---

**Функциональный объект**

```
class data_pr_Comparer {
private:
    int _value;
public:
    data_pr_Comparer(int value) : _value(value) {}

    bool operator()(const data_pr& elem) const {
        return elem.first == _value;
    }
};

void foobar() {
    data_t mydata;
    int value = 0;

    data_t::iterator it = 
        std::find_if(
            mydata.begin(),
            mydata.end(),
            data_pr_Comparer(value)
        );
}
```

---

В целом оба этих подхода имеют право на жизнь, но функциональные объекты предоставляют дополнительные возможности - сохранение состояния между вызовами, например. Но, поскольку ваш пример не требует каких-то особых условий - используйте лямбду.

Comment: Так-то лямбды тоже умеют сохранять состояние между вызовами. :)

Comment: @HolyBlackCat, вы про статические переменные? Каюсь, совсем забыл про них, но тем не менее, я больше приверженец использовать объекты для таких целей. Тем не менее, ваш способ имеет право на существование, тут не поспоришь. :)

Comment: @RiotBr3aker сохранять состояние функтора между вызовами может быть чревато ошибками.

Comment: @RiotBr3aker Да нет, не про статические. Про captured переменные: `int x = 0; auto lambda = [x]() mutable -> int {return x++;}; std::cout << lambda() << lambda() << lambda(); // Здесь оригинальный x все еще равен 0.`

Comment: @HolyBlackCat, хм, даже и не встречался ни разу с таким, полезная информация, спасибо :)

Answer (score 1):

В дополнении к предыдущему ответу:

Если задача позволяет, то я бы сохранил `std::unordered_map<int, int>` вместо того, чтобы хранить вектор пар. Тогда проще получать результат, и время выполнения короче.

```
std::unordered_map<int, int>::const_iterator
check_1(const  std::unordered_map<int, int>& m, const int value)
{
    return m.find(value);
}
```

Ну а для варианта вектора пар(как у вас), существуют масса способов(не только варианты с предыдущим ответом).  Например, можно определить шаблонные функции(как вы и просили, определяем возвращающие итератор функции)

```
using data_pr = std::pair<int, int>;
using data_t = std::vector<data_pr>;
// предикат для проверки
template <int value>
bool
Pred(const data_pr& pr)
{
    return pr.first == value;
}
//сама проверка
template<int value>
data_t::const_iterator
check_2(const data_t& v)
{
    return std::find_if(v.begin(), v.end(), Pred<value>);
}
```

Может иметь место и вариант без использования альгоритмов:

```
vector<std::pair<int, int> >::const_iterator
check_3(const vector<std::pair<int, int> > &v, const int value)
{
    auto It = v.begin();
    while (It->first != value)
            ++It;
    return It;
}
```

И т.д.

Comment: спасибо за ценные советы
просто приходится извращаться - задача сжирает всю оперативную память (16ГБ ) - обработка большого массива данных, std::map как раз выжрал все и были надежны на использование вектора (поскольку словарь дополнительные 20байт на запись использует)

Comment: Если критична память, то да, словарь не подходящий контейнер... И поэтому тоже я вначале отметил, что если позволяет задача... Но если задача сжирает всю оперативную память, то скорее всего вы  не очень хорошим способом решаете задачу.  Тогда может есть смысль пересмотреть и решить другим подходом?...

Answer (score 0):

поскольку у меня в задаче сжиралась вся память (16ГБ), то нашел более оптимальный способ (опять же для моей задачи):

делал 2 прохода по всем данным, создав таблицу, где `data_pr.first` служило как индекс в таблицу на 8ГБ - таблица для значений в диапазоне 0x00000000 - 0x7FFFFFFF и затем таблица в диапазоне 0x80000000 - 0xFFFFFFFF

если требуется для такой таблицы больше памяти (хранится не 32 битное число, а выше), то диапазон сужается

В итоге работало быстро и памяти хватило